# What a minimal OLE container have to implement?

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, ole

I am trying to understand how OLE works. This is what I have found out so far:

The server implements the `IOleObject` interface, the container implements the `IOleClientSite` and `IOleContainer` interface. The container give it to server using the `SetClientSite` method.

What's next? `IOleClientSite` have a method to get the `IOleContainer`.. But how does the server know where to draw?

I am trying to debug a java-based ole container. It is in Java + C (no C++).  I need some hints / background information to proceed.

Comment: Why do you want to use a Microsoft specific Object model in Java (not microsoft) and C (not object orientated)?

Comment: For background information start with the documentation. That's what it's there for. There are about 20 interfaces you need....  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686586(v=vs.85).aspx. **But see this:**  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304562 for an easier way. They easiest way is to host a WebBrowser control, and let that do all the work.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, that's existing code. I am just trying to trace/understand/debug it.

Comment: @Ben the document on IOleInPlaceSite helps. Why don't you put it in answer so I can accept it?